# Flip the fill variable with geom_bar(position="fill, stat = "identity) in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code :

```
newdf %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = smoke_status, y = Count, fill = Birth_status)  +
  xlab("Smoking Activity") +
  ylab("Proportion") +
  labs(fill = "Birthweight") +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

How can I change the plot so that the percentage in red corresponding to "low birth weight" is at the bottom of the bar chart?

Thank you in advance!

If you want to test with my dataframe I used the opt dataset from the medicaldata package:

```
install.packages("medicaldata")
library(medicaldata)

newdf = opt %>% 
  filter(BL.Cig.Day != "NA", Birthweight != "NA") %>%
  select(c(cig = BL.Cig.Day, Birthweight)) %>%
  mutate(cig = as.double(cig), Birthweight = as.double(Birthweight)) %>%
  mutate(smoke_status = case_when(cig >= 9 ~ "High", cig <9 ~ "Normal"),
         Birth_status = case_when(Birthweight < 2500 ~ "Low", Birthweight >=2500~ "Normal")
         ) %>%
  group_by(smoke_status, Birth_status) %>%
  summarize(Count = n())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reverse the stack order via `position = position_fill(reverse = TRUE)`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(newdf) +
  aes(x = smoke_status, y = Count, fill = Birth_status)  +
  xlab("Smoking Activity") +
  ylab("Proportion") +
  labs(fill = "Birthweight") +
  geom_bar(position = position_fill(reverse = TRUE), stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
newdf <- structure(list(smoke_status = c("High", "High", "Normal", "Normal"), Birth_status = c("Low", "Normal", "Low", "Normal"), Count = c(
  10L,
  34L, 4L, 44L
)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), groups = structure(list(smoke_status = c(
  "High",
  "Normal"
), .rows = structure(list(1:2, 3:4), ptype = integer(0), class = c(
  "vctrs_list_of",
  "vctrs_vctr", "list"
))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), .drop = TRUE))
```